# Flutter TextFormField controller into Text

Tags: flutter, dart, text, textformfield

i have a problem :( I have a Detailform with Text Widget wehre im getting values from my DB.
I have one TextFormField with a controller, because i need to set the actual price, after i submitted it, the new value will updated in a TextValueField, but i want it to show on a normal Text widget.

i hope you can understand my problem. but here my code

```
          TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'actual cost'),
                      controller: _profitController,
                      keyboardType:
                          TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      onSubmitted: (val) {
                        double amount =
                            double.parse(selectedEntry.amount); // 1 value
                        double aktPrice =
                            double.parse(val); // 2 value from this textfield
                        double profit = aktPrice * amount; // calc

                        _endProfitController.text = profit.toString();

                        newProfit = profit;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "profit"),
                      controller:
                          _endProfitController, //this is getting updated with the controller
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'test profit: ' +
                          _endProfitController.text.toString() + newProfit.toString() +
                          ' €', // this is not getting updated, and newProfit says "Null"...
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                      ),
                    ),
```

alright, how can i get the value in my Text Widget ?
I tried to setState in the onSubmitted but then the controller also isn't updating.

I tried to declare a new double newProfit but after submit it still gives me null back....

hope someone can help me :)

best regards
And thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not updating because the widgets are already built when you change the text value of the controller if you are creating the form inside a stateful widget you can call setState() inside the onChanged so the value of the field updates the String you'll use to show the text, something like this.

```
TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "profit"),
                controller:
                    _endProfitController, //this is getting updated with the controller
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    valueText = _endProfitController.text;
                  });
                  print(valueText);
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'test profit: ' +
                    valueText +
                    ' €', // this is not getting updated, and newProfit says "Null"...
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                ),
              ),
```

The variable that will get the value of the controller's text has to be outside the build method

```
String valueText = '';
```

If you are not building this inside a stateful widget you can look at the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to update a value that has no state

Comment: Hello Jaime,
this still doens't work for me....
I have a Statefull Widget, my valueText var is outside the build method.
I tried it with the setState and the print like u but nothing happen when i submitted the first textfield.

But for example i dont want the second Textformfield in my form, i just got it because that was my only way to update the value.

I need the one TexFormField with the onSubmitted where the calculation is, and this value i need to get into the Text widget